# hue file browser :server error 500

Tags: hue

Trying to open hue file browser and it gives this error, please advise with a  solution.

Server Error (500)

Sorry, there's been an error. An email was sent to your administrators. Thank you for your patience.

```
enter code here
```

Filename:
/usr/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py

/usr/share/hue/apps/filebrowser/src/filebrowser/views.py
/usr/share/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py
usr/share/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py`

Answer (score -1):

you might be logged in hue browser as admin.

try to create user as hdfs and try to login then you will see files under file manager.